# read contents from email and save it to database using php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I want to fetch specific data from email contents and save it to respective fields in mysql database. I am using imap to open email account by my script but don't know how to select specific data and save it to database.

need some help.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$server = "{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX";
$username = "abc@gmail.com";
$password = "**********";
$mbox = imap_open("$server", "$username", "$password") or die(print_r(imap_errors()));

$num = imap_num_msg($mbox);
if($num > 0) {
        $header = imap_headerinfo($mbox, 1);
        $from = $header->from;
        echo '<div>';
        foreach($from as $id=>$object) {
            //echo '<span>';
                echo $fromaddress = $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host;
        }
        echo $subject = $header->subject;
        echo $date = $header->date;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $body = imap_body($mbox, $num);
        echo '</div>';

        $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
        mysql_select_db('emails', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

        $query = "INSERT INTO emails (fromaddress, subject, date, body) VALUES('$fromaddress', '$subject', '$date', '$body')";
        mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

        //imap_delete($mbox, 1);
        imap_expunge($mbox);
        header('refresh: 3');
} else {
        header('refresh: 20');
}

imap_close($mbox);

?>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: what you have tried? post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achive this? First try to get the email content by PHP then proceed further.

Comment: I am getting email content by php.